# linux shell `sed` result to variable,`line 51: 422: command not found`

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, echo

```
HTTP_CODE= `echo "[{"key":"usernameError","message":"用户名错误"}] 422" | sed -En 's/^.* ([0-9]+)$/\1/p'`
echo "${HTTP_CODE}"
```

echo "[{"key":"usernameError","message":"用户名错误"}] 422" | sed -En 's/^.* ([0-9]+)$/\1/p' return 422

but `to var` command not found

Comment: Please take a look: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Remove the space after the =.

Comment: thanks,my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the space after the =. I made a mistake